# Como usar o GestureDetector?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de um exemplo prático para esse método, pois quero que detete movimento para esquerda executa um comando e se for para direita executa outro comando.

Buscando na net encontrei este código parece estar funcionado, porém ele não deteta movimento por ter vários botões se alguém souber como corrigir esse problema. [Link onde encontrei o código](http://www.portalandroid.org/comunidade/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5167)

```
public class MinhaActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {

    private GestureDetector detector = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    
        this.detector = new GestureDetector(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(this.detector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
             return true;
        }
         return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
         return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > 250) {
            return false;
        }
        // Movimento da direita para esquerda
        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 200) {
            //Faz algo aqui....
        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 200) {
            //Faz algo aqui....         
        }

    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) { }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2, float arg3) {
         return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) { }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
         return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para conseguir detectar o movimento de *swipe* por cima dos botões ou de qualquer outra *view*, sem que ter que implementar essa lógica em cada uma das *views*, temos de encontrar um modo de interceptar esse movimento antes delas.

A classe [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) tem o método [onInterceptTouchEvent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) que, quando implementado, permite interceptar os *MotionEvent* que são enviados às *views* filhas.
Se o método retornar `true`, o *MotionEvent* será passado ao método `onTouchEvent()` da *ViewGroup*, caso contrario, é passado ao `onTouchEvent()` da *view* onde ocorreu o evento.

Teremos então de escrever uma classe que herde de um *ViewGroup*(no caso *FrameLayout*) e implemente os métodos `onInterceptTouchEvent()` e `onTouchEvent()` de forma a tratar o movimento de *Swipe*.

```
public class SwipeInterceptor extends FrameLayout {

    public interface OnSwipeListener{
        public void onSwipeLeft();
        public void onSwipeRight();
    }

    private OnSwipeListener mSwipeListener;
    private int mTouchSlop;
    private boolean mIsDragged;
    private float mLastX;
    private float mLastY;
    private float mStartX;
    private float mDeltaXTotal = 0;

    public SwipeInterceptor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setTouchSlop(context);
    }

    //Api level 21 ou superior
/*  public SwipeInterceptor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        setTouchSlop(context);
    }*/

    public SwipeInterceptor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setTouchSlop(context);
    }

    public SwipeInterceptor(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setTouchSlop(context);
    }

    public void setOnSwipeListenner(OnSwipeListener listener) {
        mSwipeListener = listener;
    }
    private void setTouchSlop(Context context){
        ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
        mTouchSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mLastX = event.getX();
                mLastY = event.getY();
                mStartX = mLastX;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mIsDragged = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                float xDelta = Math.abs(x - mLastX);
                float yDelta = Math.abs(y - mLastY);

                float xDeltaTotal = x - mStartX;
                if (xDelta > yDelta && Math.abs(xDeltaTotal) > mTouchSlop) {
                    mIsDragged = true;
                    mStartX = x;
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mIsDragged && mSwipeListener != null) {
                    if(mDeltaXTotal > 0)
                        mSwipeListener.onSwipeRight();
                    else mSwipeListener.onSwipeLeft();
                }
                mIsDragged = false;
                mDeltaXTotal = 0;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();

                float xDelta = Math.abs(x - mLastX);
                float yDelta = Math.abs(y - mLastY);

                 mDeltaXTotal = x - mStartX;
                if (!mIsDragged && xDelta > yDelta && Math.abs(mDeltaXTotal) > mTouchSlop) {
                    mIsDragged = true;
                    mStartX = x;
                    mDeltaXTotal = 0;
                }
                mLastX = x;
                mLastY = y;
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Como se pode verificar o método `onInterceptTouchEvent()` só retorna `true` no caso de `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`, pois é apenas esse o movimento que queremos interceptar.

Todo o código se resume a alguma matemática para saber se o movimento feito deve ser considerado como um *Swipe* e qual a sua direcção.

A classe declara a interface `OnSwipeListener` com os métodos `onSwipeLeft()` e `onSwipeRight()` que serão chamados quando esses movimentos forem detectados.
A classe que os implementar deve ser registrada através do método `setOnSwipeListenner()`.

### Implementação

A implementação passa por, primeiro colocar o seu *layout* dentro do nosso *FrameLayout*

```
<nome_da_sua_package.SwipeInterceptor xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe">

        <!-- coloque aqui o seu layout -->

</nome_da_sua_package.SwipeInterceptor>
```

e depois, implementar a interface `OnSwipeListener`.
Uma das formas possíveis é fazer a sua *Activity* implementá-la:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSwipeListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Obtém a referência ao SwipeInterceptor.
        SwipeInterceptor swipe = (SwipeInterceptor)findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        //Registra a nossa Activity para receber os eventos onSwipeLeft e onSwipeRight
        swipe.setOnSwipeListenner(this);
    }

    // Declaração dos métodos da interface OnSwipeListener
    @Override
    public void onSwipeLeft() {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Swipe Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipeRight() {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Swipe Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

<sub>**Fonte de inspiração:** [Documentação](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) do Android e este [artigo](http://neevek.net/posts/2013/10/13/implementing-onInterceptTouchEvent-and-onTouchEvent-for-ViewGroup.html).</sub>

Comment: tenho uma pergunta este método é para qual versão do `Android `

Comment: Julgo que funciona em qualquer versão.

Comment: to achando que funciona no API 11 e superior, precisava testar nesse API, to usando genymotion mas tem esse API.

Comment: Não entendi a sua dúvida.

Comment: é que eu precisava dessa versão do android para testar, to usando genymotion que um ótimo emulador para testar as aplicação, então eu fiz uma pergunta a respeito mas ninguém respondeu ainda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69598/como-instalar-api-11-do-android-no-genymotion

Comment: Se o *genymotion* não tem essa versão não há nada a fazer.

Comment: a respeito da sua resposta como usar para ficar trocando de layout exemplo tenho 3 layout ao fazer o movimento para direita ele vai trocando de layout, hora que acabar ele repete assim o mesmo para esquerda

Comment: O melhor é usar um [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso (refactory):
adicione o atributo:

```
private GestureDetector gesto;
```

depois no onCreate use esse código:

```
CustomGestureDetector customGestureDetector = new CustomGestureDetector()
gesto = new GestureDetector(this, customGestureDetector);
View v = new RelativeLayout(this);
v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
      gesto.onTouchEvent(event);
      return true;
   }
});
```

Vamos tentar usando método.
Adicione esse método:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gesto.onTouchEvent(event);

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

e esse:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (e1.getX() < e2.getX()) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Left to Right swipe performed");
        }

        if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Right to Left swipe performed");
        }

        if (e1.getY() < e2.getY()) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Up to Down swipe performed");
        }

        if (e1.getY() > e2.getY()) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Down to Up swipe performed");
        }

        return true;
 }
```

Comment: `v.setOnGestureListener(new OnGestureListener(){` esta apresentado erro nessa linha será que não esta faltando nada no código?

Comment: Fiz uma edição no código. da uma olhada se agora funfa.

Comment: ainda não, esta apresentando problema `customGestureDetector` erro -->`customGestureDetector cannot be resolved to a variable` e aqui `public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) ` erro -->`The method onFling(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float) of type CalculadoraActivity must override or implement a supertype method`

Comment: Desculpe fera faltou essa parte: CustomGestureDetector customGestureDetector = new CustomGestureDetector(); já editei o código da outra olhada.

Comment: Ainda não esta funcionando, mas mesmo assim valeu

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, bom amigo! Dá uma olhadinha se isso funciona para você:

**GestureListener.java**

```
class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{

       static String currentGestureDetected;

      @Override
      public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent ev) {
          currentGestureDetected=ev.toString();

        return true;
      }
      @Override
      public void onShowPress(MotionEvent ev) {
          currentGestureDetected=ev.toString();

      }
      @Override
      public void onLongPress(MotionEvent ev) {
          currentGestureDetected=ev.toString();

      }
      @Override
      public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
          currentGestureDetected=e1.toString()+ "  "+e2.toString();

        return true;


}
  @Override
  public boolean onDown(MotionEvent ev) {
      currentGestureDetected=ev.toString();

    return true;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
      currentGestureDetected=e1.toString()+ "  "+e2.toString();
    return true;
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // vincula o gestureDetector ao GestureListener
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());
    }

    //sempre que você tocar na tela o método onTouch() é chamado
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        //o método onTouchEvent analisa que tipo de toque foi (arrastando, etc)
        boolean eventConsumed=mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        if (eventConsumed)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,GestureListener.currentGestureDetected,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

A fonte deste código pode ser encontrada [aqui](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-gesturedetector-example.html). Se ainda tiver dúvidas ou não conseguir fazer funcionar, por favor me avise!

Comment: tenho uma leve impressão de ter tentado, bom mais vou tentar novamente esse código assim que eu arrumar o eclipse, mais vale salientar que gostaria de saber como fazer o GestureDetector funcionar em cima dos botões.